# Logging in .NET with Serilog

Tags: c#, .net, logging, asp.net-core

In my application, users can run multiple jobs, each of which will do some operations on files and output to another file. In the course of these operations I need to log any errors I run into in multiple log files, one per job.

I know that I can set up different sinks (i.e. multiple log files) in code with Serilog, so I'm injecting it into my service for performing operations and then do the logging there. This service is injected into my API controller which just calls service methods.

What I'm not sure about here is how to handle calling Serilog logging methods from within the controller, since I need to do some logging in there while still using the same sink that I'm using in my service. For example, for one job there will be one log file which is shared between the controller and the service for the duration of the job.

If I expose an Interface method like

```
public void SetLogFile(string fileName)
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.RollingFile(pathFormat: _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath + "/" + fileName + ".log",
                             outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} {SourceContext} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
        .CreateLogger();
}
```

in my service which I then call my the controller or wherever, is the configuration global and usable in my controller if I also inject the ILogger in there?

Any tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: How do you define a job? Duration of a request? Or some arbitrary background task which is independent of the request/http context?

Comment: Hi Tseng, in my case it would be set of asynchronous tasks which are called from a Web API controller endpoint.